# How to install Ubuntu alongside BitLocker encrypted Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, encryption, windows-10, tpm

How to install Ubuntu alongside BitLocker encrypted Windows 10?

If it's impossible to rely on TPM, I don't mind switching to password.

My first question is can I install Ubuntu second, on a computer with already installed Windows 10 with BitLocker, or do I need first install Ubuntu, and then Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it just works.

1. On Windows reduce the size of the system partition
2. Install Ubuntu on the new free space (the installer refers to it as "replace partition")
3. After installation is finished there will be a wall of errors, just shutdown your laptop/PC with the power switch
4. If you choose to boot Windows it'll ask for BitLocker code, input it.

Done

I rebooted to Linux, did something, rebooted to Windows, it doesn't ask for code, boots normally

Answer (score 0):

TPM will show a screen similar screen like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/281rUPPGtUQ/maxresdefault.jpg) asking for the lengthy password everytime to decrypt windows if linux is installed alongside an encrypted windows 10.

So, you will need to **pause** your bitlocker during linux installation. Or, if you have time you can turn off bitlocker before linux installation and re-encrypt after its done. TPM checks for boot environment. Linux adds a new directory called e.g. Ubuntu in EFI partition which triggers TPM if bitlocker is on.