# Weird (?) BIOS on Dell G5 5500 Laptop + BitLocker woes

Tags: system-installation, uefi, dell, laptop, bios

I'm trying to follow tutorials for installing a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu setup on my Dell G5 5500 laptop. I'm supposed to visit the BIOS and do the following:

1. Disable secure boot
2. Disable Legacy ROMS
3. Disable Fast Start

It's been almost a decade sine I had a Windows laptop and geeze, BIOS has changed! This Dell BIOS supports using the mouse, searching, etc and is pretty fancy. But it does not match any of the videos I've seen sadly.

I successfully performed item #1 (disable secure boot) but could not locate the other settings. Upon reboot I was locked out because I now need (apparently) my BitLocker key to boot because I disabled secure boot. I had to re-enable secure boot to get back to Windows.

When I do this again I'll be prepared with my BitLocker code: Will I just need to enter it this one time or is this going to be a permanent boot-time chore? Any ideas on locating those other BIOS settings or advice specifically for my G5?

Comment: Do not know bitlocker, but this discusses removing it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305270/bitlocker-is-blocking-ubuntu-20-04-installation-in-a-dual-boot-system-with-windo Dell G5 5500 Info
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2454083&p=14002765#post14002765
Dell 5500 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436198  & https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-running-windows-and-bitlocker-turned-on/15338 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135654/how-to-install-ubuntu-alongside-bitlocker-encrypted-windows-10

Comment: Unless you have a reason (like using unsigned proprietary video drivers), you don't need to turn off secure boot.  Bitlocker comes enabled by default on new machines, but unless you allow the Microsoft account setup, (which generates a recovery key), you may be stuck with the TPM registers for the decode, and as you found, those may change when you make BIOS/UEFI Settings change.  Either turn it off, or generate/save a recovery key, not everything may be backed out, like a firmware update.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Check if bitlocker is enabled, if so, disable it. I've disabled secure boot on my Dell Latitude E6430, and it's all ok. Fast start or fast boot are the same I guess, I have it disabled to, it should be in the boot menu in the BIOS. I have Legacy turned on. I don't know how you prepared your installation media, I've used [ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html). Good luck :)

Comment: The BIOS fast boot simply makes it easier to hit a function key to select things at power-up -- turn it off at your own risk.  The "fast start" you have to turn off is a Windows Power option (really buried in the settings), to prevent hibernation and skipping the normal boot entirely.